# Is Google really blocking authentication from embedded frameworks (e.g. CEF)?

Tags: chromium-embedded, google-identity

This blog post - https://security.googleblog.com/2019/04/better-protection-against-man-in-middle.html - indicates that Google is planning on blocking authentication from embedded frameworks in June, 2019.

This is a short time frame for our desktop applications that utilize CEF.

I haven't been able to find any contact information to better understand the exact timing of this change. Information in the forums indicates that I should post to stackoverflow - here I am.

Can anyone shed light on the exact timing? We are scrambling to try and determine a path forward.

Comment: Follow https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16717